# Проблема со шрифтами

Tags: sql, sql-server, шрифты

Подскажите, как можно настроить шрифты?. Проблема такая: из одного окна формы данные отправляются на сервер, и на той же форме, но только в другом окне эти данные выводится с сервера так "?????????". Буквы армянские, сервер Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Может в сервере нужно шрифты настроить?

Comment: Вероятно, дело в коллации столбца, куда записываются данные.

Comment: А может из компьютера так происходит, с русскими и английскими буквами нормально работают, а место армянскими буквами знаки вопроса выводит.

Comment: К чему гадать. Какая коллация?

Comment: коллация стоит Cyrillic_General_CI_AS

Comment: Это и есть ответ на вопрос. Cyrillic - означает кириллица, а вам, насколько я понял, нужен армянский.

Comment: Попробуйте такую коллацию: Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: Уже пробовал, не помогает. Даже в сайте Micrtsoft_а написано, что Latin1_General_CI_AS подходит для армянских букв. А может нужно сервер заново установить, и там при установке ставить Latin1_General_CI_AS ?

Comment: Вопрос решен. Просто нужно переустановить Sql Server, И для юникода выбрать Latin1_General_CI_AS, а для русских букв Cyrillic_General_CI_AS. Может кому то это поможет и не будет мучаться как я :)))

Answer (score 1):

Для начала проверьте тип данных, которые у вас хранятся на сервере - юникод или нет. посмотрите свойства таблицы - тип данных для нужной ячейки установлен в nvarchar, nchar (юникод) или varchar, char (не юникод).
Потом попробуйте выбрать что то из таблицы простым запросом через Management Studio - возвращаются данные, или знаки вопроса.

Comment: У меня стоял nvarchar, изменил на varchar разницу нету все равно возвращает знаки вопроса.

Comment: "Потом попробуйте выбрать что то из таблицы простым запросом через Management Studio - возвращаются данные, или знаки вопроса."

Comment: А может в Management есть такой настройки, откуда можно было кодировку настроить?

Comment: Вы выборку из таблицы попробуйте сделать, и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: Выбрал, нет изменение?

Comment: Что значит - нет изменения? Что выбралось то? Знаки вопроса или буквы?

Comment: Собсна, если читаете по английски, советую вот эту страницу, мне кажется, там есть ответ на вопрос: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldriverforphp/thread/82e6f866-5941-4303-b093-29fa22745fc8